# MPI Matrix Multiplication - Task sharing when size(of procs) < rows of matrix

Tags: c++, c++11, parallel-processing, mpi

I am trying to perform matrix-matrix multiplication in MPI using c++.

I have coded for the cases where `number_of_processes = number_of_rows_of_matrix_A` *(so that rows of matrix_A is sent across all processes and matrix_B is Broadcasted to all processes to perform subset calculation and they are sent back to root process for accumulation of all results into Matrix_C)* and I have also coded for the case when `number_of_processes > number_of_rows_of_Matrix_A`

I have no idea how to approach for the case when `number_of_processes < rows_of_matrix_A`.

Lets say I have 4 processes and 8 * 8 matrix_A and matrix_B. I can easily allocate first 4 rows to respective ranks of processes, i.e 0,1,2,3. How should I allocate the remaining rows so that I wont **mess up with synchronization** of the results which I get from respective processes.

Side note of my implementation:
I have used only `MPI_Recv`, `MPI_Send` for all the coding part which I have done.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: allocate rows `2n` and `2n+1` to rank `n`

Comment: I think this will only work when number of processes is half that of rows. How will we allocate if, say, we have 2 processes and 8 rows ? Is there any generalization ?

Even if there exist some generalisation, I can send it via MPI_Send, but how to make other processes wait, I mean how will those processes be informed about possibility of data sending to them, if more than one row is sent to a process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From getting suggestion from people here, I came to the below solution.

`floor(N * (j + 1)/P) - floor(N * j/P)`
Where :
`N` : Number of rows in matrix
`P` : Total number of processes available
`j` : jth process. (i.e if P = 4, j = 0,1,2,3)

Answer (score 2):

Let `N` be the number of rows and `P` the number of processes, then process `p` starts at row `floor( p*N/P )`. Try it. This gives a beautifully even distritution.

Comment: I couldn't get the idea. Processes are ranked from 0 to (num_processes - 1) right? I couldnt understand the exact mapping of rows and processes.

Lets say we have rows = 8 and processes = 4, ranks = 0,1,2,3 right ?
Calculations inside floor() turns out to be whole numbers *(p = 0, N = 8, P = 4 -> floor(0 * 8/4))*, then there isnt any point in using floor() right?
Can you please elaborate the mapping of each row to processes.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: And one more question : I can send single rows via MPI_Send and can easily receive it with MPI_Recv. But how to make other processes wait, I mean how will those processes be informed about possibility of multiple data being sent to them, if more than one row is sent to a same process. `@Victor Eijkhout`

Comment: Do every rank know the number of rows in the matrix? if not, broadcast it.

Comment: Victor advised you to use `floor(...)`, and you safest bet is to assume there is a point in using it.

Comment: Now take a deep breath and consider process `p > 0`. What is the first row? What is the last row? Does rank `0` have to send anything to `p`? if yes, how many rows? Does rank `p` have to receive any rows from rank `0`? if yes, how many rows?

Comment: You should not send rows: you should create the matrix distributed from the get-to. The only sending should be of elements of the input vector, which we can assume is also distributed.